# You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity but without 'android:exported'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-play-console, ionic-native

Error:

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:compileSdkVersion="23" android:compileSdkVersionCodename="6.0-2438415" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" package="com.easternit.ec" platformBuildVersionCode="23" platformBuildVersionName="6.0-2438415">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission android:name="com.easternit.ec.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.easternit.ec.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|orientation|screenSize" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.easternit.ec.MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:authorities="com.easternit.ec.DocumentViewerPlugin.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="de.sitewaerts.cordova.documentviewer.FileProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/documentviewer_file_paths"/>
    </provider>
    <activity android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.FCMPluginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <provider android:authorities="com.easternit.ec.opener.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="io.github.pwlin.cordova.plugins.fileopener2.FileProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/opener_paths"/>
    </provider>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"/>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"/>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="com.easternit.ec"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"/>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <provider android:authorities="com.easternit.ec.firebaseinitprovider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
</application>
```

**Updated** AndroidManifest.xml **and still have same issue**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:compileSdkVersion="23" android:compileSdkVersionCodename="6.0-2438415" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" package="com.easternit.ec" platformBuildVersionCode="23" platformBuildVersionName="6.0-2438415">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission android:name="com.easternit.ec.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.easternit.ec.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|orientation|screenSize" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.easternit.ec.MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:authorities="com.easternit.ec.DocumentViewerPlugin.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="de.sitewaerts.cordova.documentviewer.FileProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/documentviewer_file_paths"/>
    </provider>
    <activity android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.FCMPluginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <provider android:authorities="com.easternit.ec.opener.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="io.github.pwlin.cordova.plugins.fileopener2.FileProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/opener_paths"/>
    </provider>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"/>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"/>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="com.easternit.ec"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"/>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <provider android:authorities="com.easternit.ec.firebaseinitprovider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
</application>
```

Comment: maybe you miss the exported attribute on com.easternit.ec.MainActivity

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the error you posted literally tells you exactly what the problem is, how to solve it, and where to look for more information ...

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml updated with no luck. Updated file added to the question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `android:exported` property for the activities or services which have `intent-filter` in them.

```
<activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|orientation|screenSize" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.easternit.ec.MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Above part of your code does not mention `android:exported="true"` or `"false"`. In your code, this property is missing in some other activities also.

Comment: I updated AndroidManifest.xml with no luck, added to the question.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that 'android:exported' has been added to every node in your updated file.

You only need to add it to the activity, activity alias, service, and broadcast receiver nodes that contain intent-filter